# Why did one linked list's end node change from NULL to another list's next node?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, singly-linked-list

The first function, `linkAndMove`, is used for basic linking together and moving point process.

The `Union` function is used for finding all numbers in linked lists `la` and `lb` (without repeats)

My test example: `la {1,3}` `lb{3,5}`

But in the last when `la` point to NULL, and `lb` point to 5.

After first function `linkAndMove`, the list `la` changed to `{1,3,5}`

Why did `la`'s end node change from NULL to `lb`'s now node 5?

[image: Snipaste_2021-09-11_22-20-38.png]`before first function`

[image: Snipaste_2021-09-11_22-22-02.png]`after first function`

```
    void linkAndMove(slink **pNode, slink **qNode, slink **finNode,
                 int linkFlag, int moveFlag) {

    if (linkFlag == -1 || moveFlag == -1) {
        cout << "ERROR! No matched logical in basic link list process." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    switch (linkFlag) {
        case 0:
            if ((*finNode)->data != (*pNode)->data) {
                (*finNode)->next = (slink *) malloc(sizeof(MemLEN));
                (*finNode)->next = (*pNode);
                (*finNode) = (*finNode)->next;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if ((*finNode)->data != (*qNode)->data) {
                (*finNode)->next = (slink *) malloc(sizeof(MemLEN));
                (*finNode)->next = (*qNode);
                (*finNode) = (*finNode)->next;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            cout << "ERROR! No matched logical in basic link list process." << endl;
            exit(1);
    }

    switch (moveFlag) {
        case 0:
            (*pNode) = (*pNode)->next;
            break;
        case 1:
            (*qNode) = (*qNode)->next;
            break;
        case 2:
            (*pNode) = (*pNode)->next;
            (*qNode) = (*qNode)->next;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "ERROR! No matched logical in basic link list process." << endl;
            exit(1);
    }
}

void Union(slink *la, slink *lb, slink *lc) {  
    slink *pNode, *qNode;

    pNode = la->next;
    qNode = lb->next;

    int linkFlag, moveFlag;

    while (pNode != NULL || qNode != NULL) {
        linkFlag = -1;
        moveFlag = -1;

        if (pNode == NULL) {
            linkFlag = moveFlag = 1;
        } else if (qNode == NULL) {
            linkFlag = moveFlag = 0;
        } else {
            if (pNode->data > qNode->data) {
                linkFlag = 1;
                moveFlag = 1;
            } else if (pNode->data < qNode->data) {
                linkFlag = 0;
                moveFlag = 0;
            } else {
                linkFlag = 0;
                moveFlag = 2;
            }
        }

        /*if (pNode == NULL) {
            linkAndMove(NULL, &qNode, &lc, linkFlag, moveFlag);
        } else*/
        linkAndMove(&pNode, &qNode, &lc, linkFlag, moveFlag);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code provided is not a [mcve].  You also may want to consider stepping through your code with a debugger:  [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.

Because in function `linkAndMove`, the pointer `finNode` is connected to the list `la`'s node. In preivous codes, using node's `next` to connect `pNode`, so changed the `la`'s end node from NULL to that node.

The solution I found is create new node for list `lc`, that cannot infect the orignal data list `la`. Codes here.

```
  switch (linkFlag) {
    case 0:
        if ((*finNode)->data != (*pNode)->data) {  
            (*finNode)->next = initLinkNode();
            (*finNode) = (*finNode)->next;
            (*finNode)->data = (*pNode)->data;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if ((*finNode)->data != (*qNode)->data) {
            (*finNode)->next = initLinkNode();
            (*finNode) = (*finNode)->next;
            (*finNode)->data = (*qNode)->data;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    default:
        cout << "ERROR! No matched logical in basic link list process." << endl;
        exit(1);
}
```